# Error in Azure Data Pipeline to get user details from Microsoft 365 need to opt in to Microsoft Data Connect

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, microsoft365

I need to retrieve all Microsoft 365 users within our tenant and extract these info to Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory

Here's my linked service as source
[image]

I encountered an error that I have to opt in to Microsoft Data Connect

[image]

does it have cost even the data set I'm going to use is BasicDataSetv0.User_v1 because in the microsoft page it says it's free only for BasicDataSetv0.User_v0

[image]

Also upon checking there's an approval stage after running the pipeline is there a way to auto approve it? Because I want to have this copied daily at a specific time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the rest api linked service to call graph api instead and it's free